# Angularjs routeprovider.when for set of conditions and one controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have 3 urls(blog, help, tips) for routing which will be having same controller and same html page.

```
rcapp.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider

    .when('/csv-validation',{

        templateUrl:'csv-validation.html',
        controller:'csvController'
    })
    .when('/blog',{

        templateUrl:'blog_tips.html',
        controller:'blogTipsController'
    })
    .when('/tips',{

        templateUrl:'blog_tips.html',
        controller:'blogTipsController'
    })
    .when('/help',{

        templateUrl:'blog_tips.html',
        controller:'blogTipsController'
    })
});
```

can i do it in one .when condition for those 3 urls.

Comment: You mean, a single page, but have three links as blog, tips, help

Comment: yes i mean i want to write only one .when condition that will check if the url link is among those three(blog, help, tips) @rroxysam

Answer (score 2):

Not a single `.when`, but you can put it in a loop:

```
rcapp.config(function($routeProvider) {

    var rp = $routeProvider

    .when('/csv-validation',{

        templateUrl:'csv-validation.html',
        controller:'csvController'
    });

    angular.forEach(['/blog', '/tips', '/help'],
       function(path) { rp = rp.when(path, {
               templateUrl:'blog_tips.html',
               controller:'blogTipsController'
           });
       });
});
```

Or I think you could use array.reduce:

```
['/blog', '/tips', '/help'].reduce(function(rp, path) {
    return rp.when(path, {
        templateUrl:'blog_tips.html',
        controller:'blogTipsController'
    });
}, rp);
```